# Shell script cannot connect to Oracle since update from Oracle 8 to Oracle 10

Tags: oracle, bash, shell

I have a shell script that connects to a Oracle database.

```
function getdata {
    sqlplus user/pass -s <<EOF
    select c1 from t1;
    exit;

EOF
}
```

The database has been upgraded from Oracle 8 to Oracle 10 and now the results file which should contain database results just contains the Oracle help text.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production

Copyright (c) 1982,2010,Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V

    -H             Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
                   usage help.
    -V             Displays the SQL*Plus version.

Usage 2: sqlplus [ [<option>] [<logon>] [<start>] ]

  <option> is: [-C <version>] [-L] [-M "<options>"] [-R <level>] [-S]

    -C <version>   Sets the compatibility of affected commands to the
                   version specified by <version>.  The version has
                   the form "x.y[.z]".  For example,-C 10.2.0
    -L             Attempts to log on just once,instead of
                   reprompting on error.
    -M "<options>" Sets automatic HTML markup of output.  The options
                   have the form:
                   HTML [ON|OFF] [HEAD text] [BODY text] [TABLE text]
                   [ENTMAP {ON|OFF}] [SPOOL {ON|OFF}] [PRE[FORMAT] {ON|OFF}]
    -R <level>     Sets restricted mode to disable SQL*Plus commands
                   that interact with the file system.  The level can
                   be 1,2 or 3.  The most restrictive is -R 3 which
                   disables all user commands interacting with the
                   file system.
    -S             Sets silent mode which suppresses the display of
                   the SQL*Plus banner,prompts,and echoing of
                   commands.

  <logon> is: (<username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>] | /)
              [AS SYSDBA | AS SYSOPER] | /NOLOG

    Specifies the database account username,password and connect
    identifier for the database connection.  Without a connect
    identifier,SQL*Plus connects to the default database.

    The AS SYSDBA and AS SYSOPER options are database administration
    privileges.

    The /NOLOG option starts SQL*Plus without connecting to a
    database.

  <start> is: @<URL>|<filename>[.<ext>] [<parameter> ...]

    Runs the specified SQL*Plus script from a web server (URL) or the
    local file system (filename.ext) with specified parameters that
    will be assigned to substitution variables in the script.

When SQL*Plus starts,and after CONNECT commands,the site profile
(e.g. $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql) and the user profile
(e.g. login.sql in the working directory) are run.  The files may
contain SQL*Plus commands.

Refer to the SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference for more information.
```

Comment: Try changing the `-s` to `-S` i.e small s to big S. `sqlplus user/pass -S`

Answer (score 1):

**option** should be before **logon** so `sqlplus -s user/pass`